# Risks of pg_start_backup()

Tags: postgresql, backup

I want to know the risks of the `pg_start_backup()` control function.

For example, what will happen if someone resets the server, or if there is a power failure during `pg_start_backup`'s operation?

What will happen if something goes wrong with the `postgres` process and it just gets out?

What will happen if the hard drive goes full with this option enabled?

Comment: `pg_start_backup` will perform a checkpoint, it  ensures the data file is at least as new as the checkpoint. ? What do you mean about during `pg_start_backup` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and most importantly, *the great majority of users should simply use `pg_basebackup`*. For those few it is unsuitable for, there are existing tools you should use instead of rolling your own, like PgBarman, WAL-E and OmniPITR.

---

If the server crashes mid-backup when using `pg_basebackup` you might need to remove the `backup.label` file from the data directory manually. It can result in some increased table bloat while it's running but is otherwise very safe.

Note that PostgreSQL 9.6 addresses the issue with the leftover `backup.label` file by providing a new API that returns the backup label file over the SQL connection. See [the release wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/NewIn96#New_API_for_hot_physical_backups) and [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP). You should strongly prefer to use this mode when backing up 9.6 or newer.

Comment: Where can I read a bit more about this API?

Comment: Oh, I was mistaken, it's in 9.6. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/NewIn96#New_API_for_hot_physical_backups

Comment: pg_basebackup will work for the initial backup on binary replication?

Comment: Yes. That's why the manual advises that you use it.